# How to set default value in DataTable Column

Tags: c#

I have `DataTable` with date column. I would like to know how to set default value of the column to current date without using loop.

I have check below code, but I would like to know what is "Value" in below code

```
var col = result.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(CellObject));
col.DefaultValue = new CellObject { Value = null };
```

Updated Code2 :-

```
var col = ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("LastUpdatedDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
col.DefaultValue = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956513/datacolumn-set-a-default-value

Comment: check my ccomments above

Comment: You need to see at CellObject constructor to see the what Type the Value is.

Comment: What's `CellObject`?

Comment: I have tried above but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ill try again.

Is `CellObject` a class you have defined? its doesn't appear in the docs for Datatable. DefaultValue takes an object.

From the context id assume .Value is a property in the CellObject class, and your constructor is setting it to null.

Have you tried

```
var col = result.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(CellObject));
col.DefaultValue = new CellObject { Value = DateTime.UtcNow();};
```

That's assuming .Value is a datetime or variant.